# How to copy files from Windows machine to Linux board over serial to USB connection?

Tags: linux, embedded

I want to copy files from Windows machine to Nitrogen board based on Linux. Nitrogen board has serial interface but my laptop doesn't so I use a serial to USB converter. COM6 is the port on laptop. Username on board is root and machine name of board is also root. I read about scp but I came to a conclusion that needs ip.

Comment: You could use `putty`+`extraputty`+`sz` (or hyperterminal if it is still available in windows) at windows side and `rz` program (part of lszrz package) at linux side. See http://www.extraputty.com/features/zmodem.html

Comment: It is not clear what your programming problem is. What part of this is it that you are struggling to program? The question, as it currently stands, is far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

ZMODEM is a good option, available through XTERM or ExtraPuTTY.

You set one side (Linux) to receive bytes (files), and send using the terminal emulator from the other side. ZMODEM has an advantage over the older protocol XMODEM in that you can initiate everything from the sending side, similar to FTP.